# Finding wildcard overlaps in less than O(n^2) time

Tags: algorithm

Lets say I have an list of tuples of equal length, where every element is either an integer or a "star", for example:

```
[
(1, 2, *, 4, 5),
(1, *, 3, 4, 6),
(1, *, 3, 4, 5),
(1, 2, 3, 4, 6),
(4, *, *, 5, 6),
(*, *, 1, 5, 6)
]
```

In this case, elements 1 and 3 overlap, 2 and 4 overlap, and 5 and 6 overlap.

Is there a way to determine if there is an overlap (I don't actually need all overlaps, just answer if there's no overlaps or at least one) in less time than the trivial approach, of checking all possible pairs against each other (which is `O(n^2)` naturally).

*Clarifications from comments*:

- `n` given above is the number of rows. This is the thing that could get large. For the purposes of this problem, assume the number of columns is relatively small, say no more than 20.
- The "stars" represent EXACTLY one element.

Comment: you can create a trie with nodes as integers and then scan all elements of current node if operation is * else go to that child.

Comment: I think you start with the last two columns, since those are the columns with no stars. They divide the list into three groups, the (... 4, 5) group, the (... 4, 6) group, and the (... 5, 6) group. That way, there are only 3 pairs to check (since each group has only two members) instead of 15.

Comment: What is the range of the integers ? Are they bounded by a relatively small value?

Comment: Checking all pairs is O(n^2 k) where n is the number of tuples and k is the number of elements per tuple.

Comment: @Damien they're not particularly bounded. In my application they're actually strings. And the number of unique strings is probably more than `n` itself (i.e. every extra tuple adds on average more than one unique string).

Comment: @AlbinPaul Wouldn't the complexity explode exponentially for input strings with lots of wildcards? Because you'd have to loop and recurse each time you hit *.

Comment: In your example all internal arrays (tuples) have the same length. Is this always true? Does `*` correspond to exactly **one** free value, or may it match with zero, two or more literal values?

Comment: Your matrix has 6 rows and 5 columns: what is `n`?

Comment: @trincot n is the number of rows (for the purpose of the problem I'm trying to solve, one can assume that the number of rows is far greater than the number of columns, I've probably got at most 10-15 columns). '*' is EXACTLY one free value.

Comment: @relatively_random yes, it would go exponentially for worst case. And Its similar to this problem.
https://leetcode.com/problems/design-add-and-search-words-data-structure/description/. They have constrained * to 2 in that problem.

Answer (score 5):

Since the columns can be ordered in any way, the trie concept may be less useful so long as there are columns without wildcards since those can partition, reducing the search space, the more unique elements they contain. I'd suggest ordering the columns by (1) number of wildcards ascending (2) number of unique elements descending, and perform a DFS, prioritising the next group to queue by the highest ratio of total wildcards in it excluding any wildcards used for the next partition.
For example, input:

```
(1, 2, *, 4, 5),
(1, *, 3, 4, 6),
(1, *, 3, 4, 5),
(1, 2, 3, 4, 6),
(4, *, *, 5, 6),
(*, *, 1, 5, 6)
```

Ordered columns right to left:

```
A (2, *, 1, 4, 5),
B (*, 3, 1, 4, 6),
C (*, 3, 1, 4, 5),
D (2, 3, 1, 4, 6),
E (*, *, 4, 5, 6),
F (*, 1, *, 5, 6)
```

First partition:

```
{A, C} {B, D, E, F}
 1/4       5/16     wildcard ratio
```

Second partition:

```
{B, D} {E, F}
 1/6    4/6         wildcard ratio
```

Etc.

Comment: I wonder if with some clever trick we could use [scikit-learn's DecisionTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) for that, or if the algorithms need to be rewritten from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Slight simplification to the other answer. The numbers form disjoint sets, and then, for each edge, add the stars to all positions that are in the incoming edge. Then in the DFS, prioritize by amount of tuples, regardless of whether they are stars. (Prune if only one tuple is left, no overlap.)

[image: Example provided.]

I think in the worst case we have all unique numbers and one star in the first position, and only find out at the end that it is unfeasible. Considering a fixed tuple, I think it would be O(`tuples`).